# Codeigniter not DLTK indexing in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter

I'm using eclipse Juno to coding `Codeigniter` with `PHP Dev Tools` plugins.

But eclipse is not indexing all file class in `system/core` (Not sugesstions)

Can anyone tell me why? how to fix this?
Thanks for reading
Best regards

Comment: do you have some error messages, etc that can help us understand your issue better.

Answer (score 0):

It's working on my eclispe INDIGO. Try to create another project with the same location of the CI files. Maybe some unexpected import error occurred.